# Build errors when trying to install pylibmc

Tags: python, pip, libmemcache

Just got a new laptop, setting up my dev environment from scratch, and I'm getting this weird error that doesn't seem to be a result of missing dependencies (though I could be wrong). I'm working in a virtualenv with Python 2.7.3. Libevent, libmemcached and memcached were all installed with Homebrew earlier.

```
(grlli)Tylers-MacBook-Pro:grlli tyler$ pip install pylibmc
Downloading/unpacking pylibmc
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pylibmc

Installing collected packages: pylibmc
  Running setup.py install for pylibmc
    building '_pylibmc' extension
    cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DUSE_ZLIB -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing
    _pylibmcmodule.c:1895:33: error: member reference base type 'const void' is not a structure or union
                               svr->hostname, svr->port);
                               ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:56:62: note: expanded from macro 'snprintf'
      __builtin___snprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)
                                                                 ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Users/tyler/projects/envs/grlli/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/tyler/projects/envs/grlli/build/pylibmc/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/1_/jkd0_x495gs0g8v7z2pgz3bc0000gn/T/pip-E_pLFk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/tyler/projects/envs/grlli/bin/../include/site/python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building '_pylibmc' extension

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/include -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DUSE_ZLIB -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _pylibmcmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/_pylibmcmodule.o -fno-strict-aliasing

_pylibmcmodule.c:1895:33: error: member reference base type 'const void' is not a structure or union

                           svr->hostname, svr->port);

                           ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/include/secure/_stdio.h:56:62: note: expanded from macro 'snprintf'

  __builtin___snprintf_chk (str, len, 0, __darwin_obsz(str), __VA_ARGS__)

                                                             ^



1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Users/tyler/projects/envs/grlli/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/tyler/projects/envs/grlli/build/pylibmc/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/1_/jkd0_x495gs0g8v7z2pgz3bc0000gn/T/pip-E_pLFk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /Users/tyler/projects/envs/grlli/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/tyler/projects/envs/grlli/build/pylibmc
Storing complete log in /Users/tyler/.pip/pip.log
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you solve it? Was it your XCode version?

Comment: Didn't really solve it, the install just magically worked one time. Sorry I don't have a good answer for you :( XCode and CLI tools are the most recent (4.5.2).

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. The one thing that fixed it for me was updating setuptools to the latest version.

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install pylibmc 1.2.3, it helped me.

Comment: That's the one I was using actually. Strangely it just decided to work once. Not sure what the difference was.